# Delete certain nodes from the beginning and the end and remove duplicates in between

Tags: xslt-2.0

Consider this XML:

```
<a>
   <b>something</b>
   <b>something</b>
   <M>other</M>
   <b>something</b>
   <b>something</b>
   <N>else</N>
   <b>something</b>
   <b>something</b>
   <b>something</b>
</a>
```

Now I want to remove all "b" at the beginning or the end and if they are in between different nodes i want only one to be output. So this would be the desired output:

```
<a>
   <M>other</M>
   <b>something</b>
   <N>else</N>
</a>
```

I don't know how many "b"s there are and I don't know what the other nodes names are. The beginning is quite easy: remove all "b" when they follow a "b":

```
<xsl:template match="b[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::b]]"/>
```

Then remove the first "b":

```
<xsl:template match="b[position= 1]"/>
```

And the last if only one "b":

```
<xsl:template match="b[position= last()]"/>
```

But i can't get the first of the last three "b"s away. The test should say: If only "b" but nothing else follows then remove "b". Some solutions I found make use of grouping but as the order of the nodes is important that doesn't seem to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `xsl:for-each-group` as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::b)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(current-grouping-key())">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(position() = (1, last()))">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<a>
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <M>foo</M>
    <b>3</b>
    <b>4</b>
    <N>bar</N>
    <b>5</b>
    <b>6</b>
    <b>7</b>
</a>
```

into

```
<a>
   <M>foo</M>
   <b>3</b>
   <N>bar</N>
</a>
```